# Uploading a file in SpringMVC via ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, file-upload

First of all I was searching and trying many ways which are described on stackoverflow but it still doesn't work.

I can't upload any file via ajax and SpringMVC. Here is my code. What can be wrong?

- Dynamic Web Module 2.5
- Spring 4
- tomcat 6

jsp code:

```
<input type="file" id="myName" name="myName" /><br>
<input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="uploadMeNow()"/>
```

dependencies connected to uploading:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

javascript:

```
function uploadMeNow() {
    var file = new FormData($("#myName"));

    $.ajax({
        url : "/m61/uploadMe",
        data : {file: file},
        type : "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,

        success : function(response) {

            if (response.indexOf("saved") >= 0) {
                alert('ok')
            }
        },
        error : function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);

            if (xhr.responseText.indexOf("failed") >= 0) {
                alert('not ok')
            }
        }
    });
}
```

xml:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" />
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" />
</bean>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadMe", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadMe(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println("aaa");
    return "saved";
}
```

A result: the current request is not a multipart request.

I was also trying by adding to ajax:

```
headers: {'Content-type':'multipart/form-data'},
```

result: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Please help me.

Comment: Add dataType:"multipart/form-data" in Ajax call.

Comment: Didn't work but anyway dataType is what you're expecting back from the server so I don't think it could help.

Comment: Can you try uploading file using a form submit (standard way first) and check whether your controller works fine first? - how to do this is here - https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: I've already tried it and the controller works well.

Comment: Your code seems ok. I'm just not sure about the way you send the multipart file. Could you try replacing `data : {file : file}` with `data : formData` and see if it works?

Comment: I've already tried it also. I've found a workaround. If somebody is interested I did it this way:

Comment: <form>
    <input type="file" />
</form>

and than in ajax:
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);